# Function returning indices of cell values near the chosen cell value

Tags: excel, vba, function

I try to write a function that takes a number `x_0` and vector of ordered numbers `y_0`, `y_1`, `y_2`, ..., and  determines indices `k`, `k + 1` such that `y_k <= x_0 < y_k + 1`.

Simply, between which two values of `y_k` the value `x_0` falls.
In the code below I used `x_0=10`and `y_0=2`, `y_1=5`, `y_2=7`, `y_3=11`, `y_4=13`, `y_5=16`. The function should output `(2,3)` as the value of `x_0=10` is between `y_2=7`and `y_3=11`.

[image]

Firstly I tried this but I got

> "Run time error 1004:Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class"

in the line four.

```
Function Indic(x_0, y)
    Set x_0 = Range("E10")
    XValue = x_0.Value
    y_k = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(y, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(x_0, XValue, 1))
    y_k_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(y, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(x_0, XValue, 1) + 1)
End Function
```

So I wanted to rewrite the function without using "Match" function but I ended up stuck and I dont know how to continue.

```
Function Indic(x_0, y)
    Set x_0 = Range("E10")
    XValue = x_0.Value
    Set y = Range("E12:E17")
    YValue = y.Value
End Function
Sub try()
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Debug.Print (Indic(.Range("E10"), .Range("E12:E17")))
  End With
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show some example data and mark the data your function should find? Also include the code/formula how the function `Indic` is called.

Comment: Why do you feed the function a parameter `x_0` when you set in in the function? And how are you returning a value to the function? Did you not meant to write: `Indic = y.Value`?

Comment: @JvdV just a habit, it does no harm and I recognize a function much sooner when I look at it later..and for the second part, I only want to return indices, not values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a function for this you can just use `Application.Match` directly, it finds the lower index of both. The upper one then is the `LowerIndex + 1`

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle3")

    Dim MatchResult As Variant
    MatchResult = Application.Match(ws.Range("E10").Value, ws.Range("E12:E17"), 1)

    If IsError(MatchResult) Then
        MsgBox "Matching failed", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim LowerIndex As Double
    LowerIndex = MatchResult - 1 'we need to subtract 1 because your index starts with `0` but row counting with `1`

    Dim UpperIndex As Double
    UpperIndex = LowerIndex + 1

    Debug.Print LowerIndex, UpperIndex
End Sub
```